# transitioning packages to EPEL version

Tags: centos, epel, backuppc

I have previously installed backuppc 3.1.0 from centos 5 testing. The package is now not maintaned by centos anymore.

EPEL have BackupPC version 3.3.0, but yum check-update did not suggest that this package is a replacement for the backuppc package by centos

How do I transition the backuppc centos to BackupPC EPEL?

I'm not planning to perform re-installation, as this machine have a lot of configuration done to arrive at its condition now.

Any idea?

Thanks

```
[root@backup yum.repos.d]# yum info backuppc
Loaded plugins: downloadonly
Installed Packages
Name       : backuppc
Arch       : i386
Version    : 3.1.0
Release    : 1.el5.centos
Size       : 2.5 M
Repo       : installed
Summary    : BackupPC is a high-performance, enterprise-grade system for backing up Unix, Linux
License    : GPL
Description: BackupPC is a high-performance, enterprise-grade system
           : for backing up Linux, Win32, and laptops to a server's disk.
           : Features include clever pooling of identical files, no client-side
           : software, and a powerful Apache/CGI user interface.

Available Packages
Name       : BackupPC
Arch       : i386
Version    : 3.3.0
Release    : 2.el5
Size       : 666 k
Repo       : epel
Summary    : High-performance backup system
URL        : http://backuppc.sourceforge.net/
License    : GPLv2+
Description: BackupPC is a high-performance, enterprise-grade system for backing up Linux
           : and WinXX and Mac OS X PCs and laptops to a server's disk. BackupPC is highly
           : configurable and easy to install and maintain.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem is in the capital letters, and that's why yum thinks that BackupPC is completely different package.

One way to achieve what you are trying to do is:

- save all backuppc configurations/data
- remove backuppc from your server
- install new version from EPEL
- restore configuration files/data
- start BackupPC

Configuration files (that I can see) are:

```
/etc/httpd/conf.d/backuppc.conf
/etc/backuppc/config.pl
/etc/backuppc/hosts
```

And data files are in directory:

```
/var/lib/backuppc
```

EPEL package will create config/dirs with capital letters:

```
/var/lib/BackupPC
```

so probably files won't get lost even if you don't backup them up.

If you don't feel comfortable with that, you can spin a test VM with CentOS 5, install rpmbuild, and use BackupPC source RPM package, and unpack it:

```
rpm2cpio BackupPC-3.3.0-2.el5.src.rpm | cpio -idv
```

Then in .spec file add a line:

```
Obsoletes: backuppc
```

somewhere around "Require" lines. After that rebuild RPM, transfer it to your server and install it with:

```
rpm -Uvh BackupPC-3.3.0-2.el5.i386.rpm
```

After that, you could use updates from EPEL.

Note: Please don't compile and build package on your production machine, spin a dev VM for that. If you are not feeling comfortable enough I can build a package for you.

Comment: I'll try with editing the spec file and compiling the package. Thanks